# How to open chrome app in same page rather than popup window?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app

I am trying to read data from serial device arduino (serial monitor). But I dont want app to open in new window. It should open in chrome tab.

```
//manifest.json

{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Serial Monitor",
  "description": "Monitors your serial port and allows you to read and write to it like you could with Arduino's IDE.",

  "version": "1.0.4",

  "app": {
         "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
  },

  "icons": {
    "16": "extentionAssets/icon-16x16.jpeg",
    "128": "extentionAssets/icon-128x128.jpeg"
  },

  "permissions": [
    "tabs","serial"
  ]

}

//background.js
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
    chrome.app.window.create('demo.html', {
        bounds: {
            width: 1160,
            height: 960,
            left: 100,
            top: 100
        },
        minWidth: 1160,
        minHeight: 960


});
});

chrome.runtime.onSuspend.addListener(function() { 
    // Do some simple clean-up tasks.
});

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() { 
        // chrome.storage.local.set(object items, function callback);
});
```

I also used `chrome.create.tabs` function, but it is not helping.. new tab opens and closes immediately.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you are confusing chrome extensions with chrome apps.

What you are trying to do is not possible in a chrome packaged app, your manifest file seems to be the one you need for a CPA not for an extension. Even more, you are using a background.js script that will open a new chrome app window with the demo.html page in it.

If you are refering to a chrome extension then you might want to tag your question as [google-chrome-extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome-extension).

If not, then the answer is easy: It is not possible to open tabs in chrome packaged apps, the concept of a chrome browser tab doesn't apply.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, Chrome packaged apps do not open in a Chrome tab (http://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps.html#look) and also do not have access to the Chrome tab (i.e. no access to chrome.tabs API which is limited to extensions).

Also, the chrome.serial API (http://developer.chrome.com/apps/serial.html) is limited to packaged apps and not available to extensions. To use the serial API you need to be a packaged app. To access a tab, you need to be an extension.

However, note that an app and an extension can communicate (if that's what you need) using: http://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime.html#method-sendMessage