# How to open app in same tab or new tab, not in a new window

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I want to create an app and that opens only on new window.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19560157/how-to-open-chrome-app-in-same-page-rather-than-popup-window) tells that we cannot open tab by a chrome apps. But when I access

[this gmail app](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gmail/pjkljhegncpnkpknbcohdijeoejaedia?utm_source=chrome-ntp-launcher), and [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/youtube/blpcfgokakmgnkcojhhkbfbldkacnbeo?utm_source=chrome-ntp-launcher) kind of apps opens in the same tab.

How can  I get this resolved.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are confusing Chrome Hosted Apps with Chrome Apps.

Hosted apps are more or less bookmarks. Chrome Apps are similar to native apps in that they are much more powerful but have no special access to the browser. You can open normal web content using window.open(). But you can't put your own Chrome App content inside that tab.